# strstr implementation with python and sets

Tags: python, strings, time-limit-exceeded, interview-questions, complexity

Please review my strstr implementation in terms of time/space efficiency and overall readability. I am preparing for a coding assessment coming up as I am looking to pivot my career from Physics to Computer Science. This is an exercise from the [interview practice questions on CodeSignal](https://app.codesignal.com/interview-practice/topics/strings). My implementation successfully passes all 14 tests but I get the following error when I submit my answer:

> Tests passed: 21/27. Execution time limit exceeded on test 22: Program
> exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes
> execution in a few seconds for any possible input.

```
"""strstr().

Given two strings, text and pattern, return an integer indicating the index
in the text of the first occurrence of the pattern.
"""


def strstr(text, pattern):
    """Needle in haystack O(|text|) time? and O(?) space.

    Return an integer indicating the first occurrence of pattern in the text,
    or -1 if the pattern is not part of the text.
    """
    lookup = set([pattern])
    len_text = len(text)
    len_pattern = len(pattern)
    for index in range(len_text-len_pattern+1):
        if text[index:index+len_pattern] in lookup:
            return index
    return -1


def tests():
    """Sample Tests."""
    samples = [("CodesignalIsAwesome", "IA", -1),
               ("CodesignalIsAwesome", "IsA", 10),
               ("a", "a", 0),
               ("a", "A", -1),
               ("sst", "st", 1),
               ("lrnkbldxguzgcseccinlizyogwqzlifxcthdgmanjztlt", "an", 38)]
    for text, pattern, answer in samples:
        if strstr(text, pattern) != answer:
            print(f"text: {text}, pattern: {pattern}, aswer: {answer}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests()
```

**Edit:** *Avoid using built-in functions to solve this challenge. Implement them yourself, since this is what you would be asked to do during a real interview.*

Comment: Can't you use `text.find(pattern)`?

Comment: @Marc I am not familiar with that method but the goal is to come up with our own efficient implementation: `Avoid using built-in functions to solve this challenge. Implement them yourself, since this is what you would be asked to do during a real interview.`

Comment: Got it, FYI [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

Answer (score 1):

As someone trying to pivot from physics to Computer Science, I think this solution is good, many CS graduates might not come up with a better solution first up.

Let's get some optimizations unrelated to cyclomatic complexity out of the way.

You added the `pattern` to a `set`. The lookup is constant `O(1)`, I don't see a need to do that and you can save on a high constant.

Let's take a closer look at

```py
    for index in range(len_text-len_pattern+1):
        if text[index:index+len_pattern] in lookup:
```

specifically `text[index:index+len_pattern]`, this creates a **copy** of the string for the range `index:len_pattern`.  This is an implementation detail of Python, one can just as easily imagine an optimization that does not create a copy.

[This question and its response might help explain this better.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710329/substrings-in-python-copies-in-memory)

You might be able to optimize away the object creation, again this unrelated to cyclomatic complexity.

*premature optimization is evil* - the intent above is more of a code review. Addressing you question below.

---

The runtime complexity of the loop is the equivalent of creating a copy of the `pattern` times the len of `text`

if `m` is `len(text)` and `n` is `len(pattern)` the for loop is `O(n*m)` in every iteration.

Typically in questions like these, there is an insight that is not always obvious that drives the solution resulting in a lower cyclomatic complexity. In this instance it is that the algorithm can be implemented in a single pass `O(n)` by keeping track of indexes across both the `text` and the `pattern`

```py
def strstr(text, pattern):
     
    t = 0
    len_text = len(text)
    len_pattern = len(pattern)
    i = 0
    for i in range(len_text + 1):
        if (t == len_pattern or i == len_text):
            break
        if (text[i] == pattern[t]):
            t += 1
        elif (text[i] == pattern[0]):
            t = 1
        else:
            t = 0

    if (t < len_pattern):
        return -1
    else:
        return i - t
    
def tests():
    """Sample Tests."""
    samples = [("CodesignalIsAwesome", "IA", -1),
               ("CodesignalIsAwesome", "IsA", 10),
               ("a", "a", 0),
               ("a", "A", -1),
               ("sst", "st", 1),
               ("lrnkbldxguzgcseccinlizyogwqzlifxcthdgmanjztlt", "an", 38),
               ("abcd" * 300000 + "abcde", "abcde", 1200000),]
    for text, pattern, answer in samples:
        actual = strstr(text, pattern)
        if actual != answer:
            print(f"FAILED : pattern: {pattern}, actual: {actual}, expected: {answer}")
        else:
            print(f"SUCCESS: pattern: {pattern}, actual: {actual} matched expected")
```

I added an additional text case to demonstrate the runtime, testing this with `time` module in python, the clock time of the implementation is a few milli seconds compared to the clock time of the `O(n*m)` algorithm which on my machine is aboue 21 seconds.

Comment: Yours fails for example `strstr('aaab', 'aab')`, returns `-1`. Also, are you saying that yours has lower cyclomatic complexity? And "O(n*m) in every iteration" is misleading.

Comment: I think expanding on a solution that linearly keeps track of substring match should be feasible, I'll be open to you expanding on the solution